# Linking Socket IO to Express routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm been looking around everywhere for the last few days for a way to access my socket IO instance running in Express from my routes and have not found a working solution.

The problem here is that I only run my socket IO instance at run-time and my routes and defined before that obviously.

The most promising solution I have found is one that wraps my routes in a function and requires it in my app.js file with whilst passing in the IO instance as an argument like so `var routes = require('routes')(io)`

Here is my setup:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(client) {  
  console.log(io.sockets.sockets)
}); 

app.set('port', 7777);
const routes = require('./routes/index')(io); 
app.use('/', routes);

app.listen('7777');
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
        console.log(io.sockets.sockets);
    });

    return router;
}
```

If I connect to the WebSocket, my `io.on` event fires and I get a console log of the connected sockets in the form of a fairly large object that contains the socket id's etc.

If however, I get to the route `'/test'` I get a console log of a blank object: `{}`. I would imagine this is because the instance of the socket I am passing down to the routes does not have anyone connected to it at the time hence the blank object is returned, but this is just my best guess.

Where I'm a little stuck is how to get the full instance with all live connections to the route.

Alternatively, I've thought of attaching the io instance to the request object like so in order to have access to it in the routes:

```
server.on('request', function(req, res){
    req.io = io;
}
```

but couldn't quite get it to work, nor am I sure this is the correct approach.

I imagine this must be a common issue so I would love a clear answer on how to work around this and the correct approach to tackle the issue.

**EDIT**

So I eventually got my above code working, I hit the `'/test'` endpoint from an AJAX GET request within the chrome extension instead of my just visiting the URL localhost:7777/test. What I can't understand here is why it works with an AJAX request but not page navigation? (The page navigation is done after I make the socket connection in the extension)

Comment: Actually your approach is the way to go. And actually it should work as intended

Comment: The `routes` variable is `undefined`. You should return the router in the function exported from your `routes.js`-file. It isn't an issue because Express keeps an internal state, but if you would have `app.use('/something/else', routes);`, hitting `GET /something/else` would not log anything to console, but `GET /` would, because that's what you tell the router with `router.get('/', ...)`.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I actually do return routes I just missed it when writing it in here. Thanks for the reminder - i've edited my question :)

Comment: I hesitate to "answer" this question because I suspect my workaround may be somewhat hacky, but the way I went about this was by adding a function to the router. "router.commit = function(ioObject){container.io = ioObject}" ...Then console.log(container.io.sockets.sockets)...That said, I, too, would be interested in what a best practice approach to the problem is.

Comment: Please add the bit about the Chrome extension to your question as that seems particularly relevant.  When does the Chrome extension make it's connection?  When the browser is run?  Or when a page that it's monitoring loads?

Comment: Got my above code working, see edited question above with the issue